How to create a chart with multiple series in VB with ADO.NET, with one column determining the series, one the X, and one the Y?
I am using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting to create a chart that displays sensor data from different sensors. Data is pulled from SQL Server using a stored procedure and a SqlDataReader and then stored in a DataTable with 3 relevant columns: the Name of the sensor, the Date the measurement was taken, and the Value measured. I currently make the chart with this code:
SensorChart.DataSource = dataTable
SensorChart.Series("Series1").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
SensorChart.Series("Series1")("DrawingStyle") = "Emboss"
SensorChart.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "Date"
SensorChart.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "Value"
SensorChart.Series("Series1").IsValueShownAsLabel = False
SensorChart.DataBind() 

However this just creates one chart that shows all the data points from all the sensors in one series. What I really want to do is to divide the data up so that there is a separate series for each individual sensor. So if my data is



Name
Date
Value




S1
1/1/2020
20


S1
2/1/2020
30


S1
3/1/2020
40


S2
1/1/2020
5


S2
2/1/2020
10


S2
3/1/2020
15


S3
1/1/2020
50


S3
2/1/2020
60


S3
3/1/2020
70



I want to have (20,30,40), (5,10,15), and (50,60,70) all plotted on the same chart against those dates but with each set of points being uniquely labeled with their corresponding sensor name.
